# Why do parametric tests need normal distribution of sample means?

Tags: normal-distribution, nonparametric

Every parametric test has the assumption that the sample means are following a normal distribution. This is the case if the sample itself is normal distributed or if approximately if the sample size is big enough. but why do they have that assumption? I thought the test statistic is used to make a decision and they have their own distribution (F, t, etc).

Comment: Every parametric test does *not* have this assumption. The general linear model, for example, makes assumptions about the distribution of *errors* as estimated by residuals.

Comment: Normal distribution _not_ in samples but in population. If you have statistical or methodological reasons to believe that the samples are representative of the population with normality despite that the sample distributions somewhat depart from normality (in other words, that the non-normality is just random coincidence) - you may use parametric tests.

Comment: The statement in your first sentence is false so your question appears to be predicated on a misunderstanding.

Comment: Lot of tests assume that data is independent indenticaly distributed (iid) sample. Then sample mean follows normal distribution assymptotically (the difference from normality dissapears with increasing sample size) due to central limit theorem. Assumption of iid sample is a very convenient one, so it is made frequently. You have probably mixed these two up.

Answer (score 1):

The statistic is always defined in the sense that you can (for example) get a t-value for the mean of any collection of numbers. However, the distribution of the statistic is conditional on the assumption - the t-value is only t-distributed if the sample mean is normally distributed.

For example, you might want to repeatedly simulate data which is decidedly not normally distributed (for example, a log-normal distribution) and get the t-values. They won't follow the t-distribution unless your sample size is large & your lognormal-distribution is almost normal as well. However, if you do the same with a normal distribution your t-value will actually be t-distributed.

Also note that there are lots of other parametric tests which do not make this assumption but instead another one.